# Can I create dynamic web service client reference without adding its reference to service references of the project?

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamic

I need to create dynamic references of multiple web services and sent some value with it.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Are you trying to say that you need to dynamically set the location of a web service? How do you mean dynamic - where does the information come from? More information will produce better answers.

Answer (score 2):

To be truly dynamic, you have to do three things:

1)  Get the service description (wsdl) from the web service
2)  Generate the proxy code dynamically from the service description
3)  Compile the code and expose it in your application - usually through reflection or some sort of dynamic scripting interface.

The code snippet below is from some experimenting I did a long time ago.  It is not production code and won't compile, but should give you a head start if this is the direction you want to go.

It does not include step (3).  The code generated can be compiled with classes provided in the System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(_Url + "?wsdl");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = false;
if (_User.Length > 0)
{
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_User, _Password, _Domain);
}
WebResponse response = null;

try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (System.Net.WebException wex)
{
    response = wex.Response;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}

Stream requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();
ServiceDescription sd = ServiceDescription.Read(requestStream);
_ReferenceName = _Namespace + "." + sd.Services[0].Name;
ServiceDescriptionImporter Importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
Importer.AddServiceDescription(sd, string.Empty, string.Empty);
Importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
Importer.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;

CodeNamespace nameSpace = new CodeNamespace(_Namespace);
CodeCompileUnit ccu = new CodeCompileUnit();
ccu.Namespaces.Add(nameSpace);

ServiceDescriptionImportWarnings warnings = Importer.Import(nameSpace, ccu);
if (warnings == 0)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider prov = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
    CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
    options.BlankLinesBetweenMembers = false;
    options.BracingStyle = "C";

    prov.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(nameSpace, sw, options);

    _ProxySource = sw.ToString();
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: -1: 1. Missing `using` blocks. 2. Uses the legacy ASMX technology, which should not be used for new development. 3. Doesn't indicate that it is using the legacy ASMX technology.

Comment: @JohnSaunders What would you suggest doing with modern technology?

Comment: @scott, I would use WCF. I would also carefully evaluate the requirement to be dynamic.  In my experience,  most such requirements are false.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the code right now but I know this can be done, in fact in a former company I have worked we did have a generic web service client developed in house.

have a lock here:

[Generic Web Service Proxy](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ChrisBlake/GenericWebServiceProxy11232005080848AM/GenericWebServiceProxy.aspx)

Comment: -1: unfortunately, the linked article is from 2004, and uses the legacy ASMX web service technology, which should not be used for new development.